# DataFilters in Spark explain physical plans in Databricks but not on local machine

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, databricks

I am running the same query on the same dataset with the same Spark version (2.4.0) in two different environments - the explain plan includes `DataFilters` in the output in the Databricks environment, but doesn't include this in the output on my local machine.  I'd like to understand what the `DataFilters` option means and why it's outputted inconsistently.

I have a sample Parquet dataset that looks like this:

```
parquetDF.show()
+----------+---------+---------+
|first_name|last_name|  country|
+----------+---------+---------+
|   Ernesto|  Guevara|Argentina|
|  Vladimir|    Putin|   Russia|
|     Maria|Sharapova|   Russia|
|     Bruce|      Lee|    China|
|      Jack|       Ma|    China|
+----------+---------+---------+
```

When I run `parquetDF.where($"first_name" === "Maria").explain()` on my local machine from the Spark console, I get this physical plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [first_name#25, last_name#26, country#27]
+- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(first_name#25) && (first_name#25 = Maria))
   +- *(1) FileScan parquet [first_name#25,last_name#26,country#27] 
           Batched: true, 
           Format: Parquet,
           Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/Users/powers/Documents/tmp/parquet_blog_data], 
           PartitionFilters: [], 
           PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(first_name), 
           EqualTo(first_name,Maria)],
           ReadSchema: struct<first_name:string,last_name:string,country:string>
```

When I run the same query in Databricks (Runtime 5.2) on the same file in S3, I get this physical plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [first_name#259, last_name#260, country#261]
+- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(first_name#259) && (first_name#259 = Maria))
   +- *(1) FileScan parquet [first_name#259,last_name#260,country#261] 
           Batched: true, 
           DataFilters: [isnotnull(first_name#259), (first_name#259 = Maria)], 
           Format: Parquet, 
           Location: InMemoryFileIndex[some_bucket/parquet], 
           PartitionFilters: [], 
           PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(first_name), 
           EqualTo(first_name,Maria)], 
           ReadSchema: struct<first_name:string,last_name:string,country:string>
```

What are the `DataFilters`?  Are these filters that are applied at the S3 level?  Perhaps these filters are applied before the data is sent from S3 to the ec2 cluster?

Comment: Databricks uses a custom version of Spark. That might be one of their tweaks...